# Plotting a region given by a user defined function

Tags: plotting, regions

I'm new to mathematica, so I expect this is just something simple. I've defined the following function:

```
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
  a + b - 3 Max[Select[Range[0, a, 1], b - # >= -(a - #)^2 &]]
```

and I'm then trying to plot the following 3d region

```
RegionPlot3D[
  T >= -z^2 && p >= f[z, T]&& z>=0 , {T, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}, {p, -20, 20}, 
  Evaluated -> True, PlotRange -> Full]
```

but I keep getting an error, because (I think), `RegionPlot3D` is trying to evaluate `f[z, T]` with `z`,`T` as variables. How can I make this work?

Comment: Write `f[z, T, Null]` within `RegionPlot3D`, or remove the last comma from the left hand side of the definition `f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumericQ,] := ...`

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo. But it still gives the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me. You might have an old definition of `f` still active. So restart Mathematica and reevaluate the notebook, or do this:

```
Clear[f]
f[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
  a + b - 3 Max[Select[Range[0, a, 1], b - # >= -(a - #)^2 &]]

RegionPlot3D[T >= -z^2 && p >= f[z, T] && z >= 0,  {T, -20, 20}, {z, -20, 20}, {p, -20, 20},
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much, as I suspected it was just me being silly.